# How to implement “Building a More Performant Layout” in code on WWDC18 session 220

Tags: ios, autolayout, wwdc

I recently watched the video of WWDC18. I am very interested in the example mentioned in it. There is such a problem in my own app. However, the engineer only talked about the concept and did not have the example code. I really want to know how to use the code to realize the wonderful idea in the session 220.

link:[High Performance Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/?time=1699)

[I want to know how this is implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIhI7.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are asking. In the image you shared, all of the autolayout constraints are visible (e.g. the two circular images have height + width constraints, the blue is centered based on the purple, the 3 labels have their leading + trailing edges equal). You can open a storyboard or a xib and just copy them from that picture. If you don't understand what the lines mean, I think you would be better off learning the fundamentals of autolayout first, by following one of the many tutorials online

Comment: I agree with Simon ... not sure what you are asking. The video discussion seems pretty basic: don't add / remove / change constraints unless you **must**. So, Leo J, do you have a cell for which you are messing with the constraints at run-time, and thus getting poor performance? If so, have you tried following the advice related to only changing the constraints when necessary? If you're having trouble with it, you need to post your layout and code if you want specific help.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Sorry, the question is not clear. Of course, I know how to use AutoLayout. However, the cat on the image may or may not exist...We simplify the problem, which might be like this: https://imgur.com/zKR1mrl